# How to run python code that needs input argument in Jupiter notebook, (File not found error Juypter Notebook,)

Tags: python, shell, arguments, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

my code is fine and runs when i execute it through the shell with a image as input argument.
However when I am trying to run my code in Jupyter Notebook i get the following Error:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/Users/.../Code-f'
```

Could it be because the input is needed to execute it and as i do not give any input in Jupyter it does not work?

Can anyone help me with that issue? I would like to try my code in Jupyter notebook and not only by using the shell.

This is my code:

```
import sys
import os

def main():
    script = sys.argv[0]
    map_name = sys.argv[1]
    convertToBitmap(map_name)

def convertToBitmap(map_name):
    wk_dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath('__file__'))
    map_foto = Image.open(wk_dir+map_name)
    width, height = map_foto.size
    map_bit=map_foto.resize((150,150))
    map_bit.tobitmap
    imagepathToBitMap=imagepath+".bmp"
    map_bit.save(imagepathToBitMap)
main()
```

Comment: Print out the value of `wk_dir`. Is the file you are trying to read in that directory?

Comment: yes it is, but as i get the file just by running the code as script in a shell with the file as input, obviously in Jupyter Notebook he can not find it. Any ideas?

Comment: It seems likely that `os.path.realpath('__file__')`  isn't the same in both environments. You can find out for sure by following my advice to print out `wk_dir`.